# SQL Server duplication index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I use SQL Server.

I don't know that : Why SQL Server allow you to create duplicate index.

for example you can create following index :

```
CREATE INDEX Index1 ON dbo.tb1(Col1, Col2)
CREATE INDEX Index2 ON dbo.tb1(Col1, Col2)
CREATE INDEX Index3 ON dbo.tb1(Col1) INCLUDE(Col2)
```

SQL Server performance will be improved, in SQL Server don't allow to create duplicate index.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should ask the Sybase team that originally designed the engine .....

Comment: Or just Google "why does sql server allow duplicate index" and look at the Connect item link and SQLMag link in the top few results.

Comment: @mehdi This is a bug. Can check following link:
http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/313227/sql-server-allows-to-created-duplicate-indexes

Answer (score 0):

Index this is a table. If you can have duplicates of base tables, why not to allow it for index?